# Writing zero garbage code

Tags: memory, go, garbage-collection

I'm a new to golang memory management, especially in go's GC. So wanna ask help for some articles or any explanations/advices to how to write zero(less) garbage code. I saw a Zero Garbage code in e.g. https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter project, but I don't have any idea how it's different from any other code.

Comment: This question will most probably be closed as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (see point 4). I haven't seen any articles on the topic, so I can only recommend using `-gcflags "-m"`, [testing.AllocsPerRun](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#AllocsPerRun) and [profiling your code](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) with `-memprofile`.

Comment: Basically, if you don't allocate anything, there's nothing to collect. It starts by reusing objects, and making sure temp values don't escape to the heap.